# File or database localization

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, resources

In ASP.NET which is better performance wise;

- Localization using the file based resx / resource system
- Localization by retrieving translations from a database

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Localization using the file based resx / resource system. No network latency.

Comment: Is that always the case, even when the translation list is very long? Won't a DB handle that better? Or is the latency always more.

Answer (score 0):

Normally the I/O of  file on local disk should have better performance than the I/O of database connection.

Answer (score 0):

I developped the localization part of an application to localize **both UI and data**.

I choose a database to handle this because our customer requested some flexibility to modify some elements himself (lists, typos during startup...)

As we were also concerned with network latency issue and database use, we put a **local client cache layer** in between, et voilà !

It is a memory cache, but it can be switched easily to a disk cache if the amount of translation data is getting to big.